# On Home page only Logo displaying in Magento

Tags: php, magento, debugging, html

I am working on my clients website Kraftseeds.com

The Homepage is displaying only header rest of the code is missing.

How to sort out the issue

Have actually restored the website to a week old back up but the problem persists.

Only LOGO is appearing

Answer (score 1):

You can find the report on `#yourmagento#\var\report`

the report number can be check when you open your website

> Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: **535444943634**

---

But, You can try to comment the code inside

> index.php

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

to be

```
//if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
//}
```

so you can debug.

Comment: Pls chk it now
It is displaying just the logo